# HTML input field to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, google-sheets

It seems I have it almost working, but for some reason when I'm trying to submit data from an input field to a Google spreadsheet, it does add data, but not the data that is being inputed. So in the Google spreadsheet I see a new entry with timestamp, but not the inputed data.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
$('#emailForm').one('submit',function(){
    var inputField = encodeURIComponent($('#emailForm').val());
var baseURL = 'http://docs.google.com/forms/d/1vl7imylKoya3y8bnboD7WTQ5VsdVw1YmDA1-3_66Apo/formResponse?entry.1017875735=';
var submitRef = '&submit=Submit';
var submitURL = (baseURL + emailAddress + submitRef);
$(this)[0].action=submitURL;
$('#email').addClass('active').val('Thank You!');
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#form-container').hide();
  $('#update-form').animate({'width': '0px'},300,function(){
    $('#get-updates-link').hide();
      $('#email').addClass('active').val('Thank You!');
  });
},1000); 
</script>



<form action="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1vl7imylKoya3y8bnboD7WTQ5VsdVw1YmDA1-3_66Apo/formResponse?entry.1017875735="

<form id="emailForm" action="" method="POST" target="no-target">
  <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="enter email" name="email">
  <button id="email-submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is a bit silly, but where are you using the 'inputField' variable? To my understanding, this variable contains the value of the input field, but it is not sent to the Spreadsheet...

Comment: It seems like the line should be `var emailAddress = encodeURIComponent($("#email").val());`.

Comment: FWIW: Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/at47xc3t/) I used to test the code. Unfortunately, JSFiddle doesn't handle forms well. I couldn't prevent the default submission action, but I could use a keyup event to see that data is getting in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the `var inputField`, but later during submission, you've used `emailAddress` in your submitURL code line.